# Wordpress prints menu name at the end of ul

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

I have a secondary menu in my Wordpress-Theme, and it works - the only problem is that at the end of the ul-list it prints the menu-name.

The output is something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a>One</a></li>
    <li><a>Two</a></li>
    <li><a>Three</a></li>
    secondary
</ul>
```

I can´t find where this "secondary" comes from, as I did not ask Wordpress to do that ;)

In my theme´s functions.php I register my menus like this:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => 'Primary Menu',
    'secondary' => 'Secondary Menu',
) );
```

And in my footer I call the menu:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary', 'menu_id' => 'secondary-menu' ) ); ?>
```

It´s just a weird bug somewhere - I appreciate every hint or tip on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Your menu registration looks different than the recommendation on wordpress. Have you tried setting it up like this? https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

```
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
     'secondary-menu' => __( 'Secondary Menu' )
   )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

then call just the secondary menu like this

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'secondary-menu' ) ) { /* if menu location 'primary-menu' exists then use custom menu */
  wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary-menu') ); 
}
```

Source: http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-register-menus-in-wordpress

Comment: Thanks for Your reply, but this didn´t help. Still the same output as before.. Do You have any other suggestions where this could be coming from?

Comment: I updated the code and provided an article with further instruction. Hope this solves your problem.